# Got Frame load interrupted and The url can not be shown with oauth2

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios

I am using Authenticator doing Oauth2 authentication. The return url is something like myapp://landing. I got following errors, The URL can not be shown and Frame load interrupted. It seems I can not suppress this error. I got the correct token from the service. I just want to know if there is a way I can suppress them.

Comment: So the problem is the url is malformed?

Comment: Hi ,What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't know exact what's the cause. It could be the return url.

Comment: I grab source from github ,suppress the message and made my own build. Now I don't see them anymore. Thanks all.